Why is FastAPI, uvicorn, or the network somehow taking so long to generate a response?
Context
Hello, I'm using FastAPI and Sqlalchemy to create a backend in python3.12. Fairly recently, we decided to introduce the Server Timing out of curiosity to see in which parts of the application we were spending the most time. Once we completed the implementation and took a look at the results, we were pretty astonished. Here is an example of the Timing tab from the Chrome browser:

So as you can see, out of the 395.41 milliseconds, only 13 milliseconds were actually captured by our server timing tracking code. Our first reaction was to assume that our tracking was actually really broken. After reviewing and testing the implementation, it is actually working perfectly.
I have also used cURL to get some more info about the request/response times:
Establish Connection: 0.293981s
TTFB: 1.040998s
Total: 1.041211s

For some reason, something takes a long time after establishing the connection and sending the first byte.
Not sure if helpful but this is the command to start the application:
python -m uvicorn fast_api.main:app --host 0.0.0.0

Implementation
So basically to try to track time, we just use middleware and some decorators to track different things:

Time spent in the db
Time spent in redis
Time spent in calling some third parties that we depend on

The middleware is pretty simple:
class ServerTimingMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
    async def dispatch(self, request: Request, call_next):
        self._init_tracking()
        response = await call_next(request)
        self._finish_tracking()
        response.headers["Server-Timing"] = self._generate_server_timing_header()
        return response

app.middleware("http")(catch_exceptions_middleware)
app.add_middleware(ServerTimingMiddleware) # this is the middleware
# rest of the middleware

This is a simplified example, but it gets the point across.
Question
What is going on? I'm pretty sure we must be ignoring something, but it baffles me that only 3% of the time it takes to generate the response is spent on our code. Any suggestions?

So seems, all the time is spent inside the route (response = await call_next(request))? Without seeing any of the codes for the route, the calls to the DB/redis, and whatever processing is happening inside there, this is almost impossible to answer. You already did the first steps of isolating where it's slow, but you'll then need to go deeper. Time each step of your API's flow: parsing the request (if you are using Pydantic models with complex validations, that can add some latency), calling the DB, data processing, forming the response (again, if using Pydantic, can add some time).

No no, maybe I explained wrong. I have discarded that my code is slow. The part between await call_next only takes 13 milliseconds total (12ms in the db and 1 ms in the rest)

I see, and how is your FastAPI app hosted/served? Do you have something like gunicorn or a proxy in front of your app? Are all this timings based on running on something like a k8s cluster or simply on localhost? Basically, components in between your browser and your server-side app.

It’s running on kubernetes with Ingress and Nginx. Servers are hosted in AWS. We are using unicorn with only one worker and thread (the command to start the app is in the question)

I have tried in local and the results are more or less the same (a little bit faster). So I doubt is something related to kubernetes configuration.
